# IJVM exercise, swapping 2 elements in a 4 elements stack

Tags: java, mic-1, ijvm

i'm trying to create a microprogrammed function that, given 4 values in the stack, swaps the 3rd and the fourth. I called it "mswap", this is the microcode so far:

`mswap1 SP = SP - 1
mswap2  SP = SP - 1

mswap3  MAR = SP - 1

mswap4  rd
mswap5  MAR = H

mswap6  wr
mswap7  MAR = SP

mswap8  rd
mswap9 MAR = SP - 1
mswap10 wr

mswap11 MAR = H
mswap12 rd
mswap13 MAR = SP 
mswap14 wr
mswap15 SP = SP + 1
mswap16 SP = SP + 1; goto Main1`

And this is an example program:

.main
start: BIPUSH 0x39
       BIPUSH 0x30
       BIPUSH 0x36
       BIPUSH 0x35
       MSWAP
       OUT
       OUT
       OUT
       OUT
       HALT
.end-main

It should give an output of 5690
Sad truth, the output is just 56
it's ike i "missed" two pile elements.. Is this due to excessive use of SP = SP -1? It worked just fine when writing a similar function to swap the 2nd and 3rd element

Answer (score 0):

mswap5 is using H, but H has not been set. Did you mean to set it in an earlier instruction?

Only two reads and two writes are needed.

SP does not need to be changed in order to access into the stack. Use H, then you will not have to adjust SP at the end of the routine.

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion really helped, i got this instruction working properly at last

Comment: Of course :) i thought i did already, the site probably had a bit of problems yesterday